# QGIS Display features by attribute value

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, display

I have a layer called "streets".  It has an attribute called "traveled".  The values are either "yes" or "no".  If the value is "no", I would like to display those streets in a different color (than the ones with "yes" as the value).

Also this "streets" layer has an attribute called "miles".  If the "traveled" attribute is "yes", I would like to retrieve the total "miles" from the "traveled" streets only.

Comment: Hi Rick, welcome to GIS.SE. Please make sure in the future, that you do not ask multiple questions in a single post. Otherwise answering and finding the right answer for others is unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the `properties` of your layer, choose the `style` tab and there `classified` based on the column `"travelled"`.
2. First, use the field calculator to add the column `"dist"` to your table, set it as an integer type and use the code `$length` to fill it. Then, use `sum("dist",group_by:="travelled")` to get the aggregated values.

Maybe you have to edit the second part a bit, please refer to the tooltips within the raster calculator.

Comment: The raster calculator doesn't seem relevant here. Did you mean *field* calculator?

Comment: Obviously, yes.